# why R discard decimal when as.numeric is applied?

Tags: r, decimal

Hi to all the community, 
I have the following DB:

```
ID Distance
M1_PRM    54,56
M1_PRM  4147,69
M1_PRM  1723,34
```

I use the following script to replace "," in "." in Distance as R doesn't like "," (and it works):

```
mysub<-function(x)(sub(",",".",x))
DB<-(apply(DB, 2,mysub))
DB<-data.frame(DB)
```

Then I need to convert DB$Distance `as.numeric` because I need to use 
`tapply` in conjunction with sum, like:

```
apply(DB$Distance,ID,sum)
```

When I give

```
DB$Distance<-as.numeric(DB$Distance)

ID Distance
M1_PRM 54
M1_PRM 4147
M1_PRM 1723
```

It seems that R discard the decimal!!!
Someone Know what is wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another approach (if you're reading this in from a file):

```
dat <- read.table(text = "ID Distance
 M1_PRM    54,56
 M1_PRM  4147,69
 M1_PRM  1723,34",header = TRUE,sep = "",dec = ",")
> dat
      ID Distance
1 M1_PRM    54.56
2 M1_PRM  4147.69
3 M1_PRM  1723.34
```

Answer (score 3):

@joran's Answer is the way to go, if you're reading in `DB` with `read.table` or `read.csv`, otherwise, there's `type.convert`, which takes a `dec` option.

```
type.convert(as.character(DB$Distance), dec = ",")
# [1]   54.56 4147.69 1723.34
```

Discard the `as.character`, if `Distance` is already such.

Comment: Really really useful suggestions...I start understanding that sometimes there is an easy way to obtain what we want from R!!!Many thanks to all!

Comment: @stefano, glad to help. Don't forget to accept one of the answers here before you go, so the open question is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

R is discarding decimal because you're going in the wrong way in `apply` call, instead try

```
> DB$Distance <- as.numeric(sub(",",".",DB$Distance))
> sapply(DB, class)
       ID  Distance 
 "factor" "numeric" 
> DB
      ID Distance
1 M1_PRM    54.56
2 M1_PRM  4147.69
3 M1_PRM  1723.34
```

Then use `tapply` as in:

```
with(DB, tapply(Distance, ID, sum))
```

your `apply(DB$Distance,ID,sum)` will not work, instead use `tapply(DB$Distance, DB$ID, sum)` because the correct function is `tapply` and you have to give a numeric verctor and an index, both of them are attached in `DB` so R won't find `ID` unless you use `with(.)` function or `DB$ID`.

see `?apply` and `?tapply`.

I just try to give an answer to you according to your post. @joran's answer is the direct way to go if you're importing data from a file, if so, all your problem reduces to use `dec = ","` in the `read.table` call